# Como saber se meu ambiente de desenvolvimento está compatível com AndroidX?

Tags: flutter, dart

Meu projeto foi criado há bastante tempo e não sei se ele é compatível com AndroidX como poderia identificar? E como atualizar para tornar compativel com AndroidX?
(estou utilizando vscode)

Comment: Veja esse post do próprio site do Flutter: [_Migração para AndroidX_](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration).

Comment: Eu vi mas meu inglês é péssimo, não entendi se "android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true" significa que é compatível ou não.

Comment: Se o arquivo `android/gradle.properties` (ou `.android/gradle.properties`) tiver essas "diretivas" declaradas, significa que ele está usando AndroidX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Android X**

Para entender melhor o que é o `AndroidX` leia a [Visão Geral do AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx?hl=pt-br) que explica com mais detalhes o tema. Destaque para um breve entendimento:

> O AndroidX é uma grande melhoria para a Biblioteca de Suporte original do Android, que não é mais mantida. Os pacotes do androidx substituem totalmente a Biblioteca de Suporte, fornecendo paridade de recursos e novas bibliotecas.

**Verificar projeto**

O diretório `android` dentro do projeto Flutter possui um arquivo chamado `gradle.properties` e é nesse arquivo que fica a declaração se o seu projeto Android está ou não utilizando o AndroidX. As flags abaixo determinam isso:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Caso não estejam assim no seu projeto ele não está utilizando e recomenda-se a atualização para ter maior compatibilidade com atualizações de `lib's` importadas no seu projeto Flutter.

O motivo de ser recomendado atualizar é devido a pacotes importados feitos com AndroidX não funcionarem em projetos que não utilizam o AndroidX e vice-versa. E a grande maioria dos pacotes já está vindo com ele ativo, assim se o seu projeto não estiver você ficará limitado a versão de um pacote que não tenha feito a migração.

É importante ressaltar que deverá verificar os pacotes que seu projeto está utilizando. Eles precisam ter feito a migração também. Verifique cada um deles se já estão assim na versão que seu projeto utiliza.

**Como migrar**

O melhor caminho para fazer a migração para o AndroidX é dentro da IDE Android Studio. Existe uma opção dentro dele que faz automaticamente todo o processo e permite inclusive fazer um backup da versão anterior do projeto.

Então basta seguir a [Documentação de Migração para AndroidX](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration) na página do Flutter.

---

> **Dica extra:** Ao encontrar artigos e documentação em inglês na internet, existe a opção de traduzir a página dentro do Chrome. Ele pode não ser 100% preciso na tradução mas é um grande auxiliar para pessoas que não compreendem bem o inglês. Para utilizar basta abrir o site que está em inglês, clicar com o botão direito do mouse e selecionar a opção de "Traduzir página". O inglês é muito importante mas não pode ser um tabu que te impede de evoluir no conhecimento. Utilize essa ferramente sempre que precisar e pratique bastante até chegar o momento de não depender mais dela.